# Auto-format a Java record in a single line in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, record

IntelliJ 2021.1 adds support for Java 16. And Java 16 adds the new feature of [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

When I define a record locally in IntelliJ 2021.1, the formatting command results in this format:

```java
record Grid(int[] array , int count)
{
}
```

Is there a way in the auto-formatting rules to keep a record definition to a single line rather than line-wrapping the empty curly braces?

➥ What I want:

```java
record Grid(int[] array , int count) {}
```

---

I also want SPACE character before and after each of the parentheses. But the auto-formatting rules already cover that; just seems broken for records. I assume that will be fixed eventually.

What I *really* want:

```java
record Grid ( int[] array , int count ) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve that formatting:

**Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java, Wrapping and Braces tab**

***Keep when reformatting*** section

- deselect ***Line breaks***
- select ***Simple classes in one line***
  [image]

Comment: Indeed, I get close my desired effect if *both* your red-arrow settings are in place. The curly-braces insist on a SPACE between them, which I do not want, but close enough to make me happy. Thanks.

Comment: @BasilBourque The SPACE could be removed from by disabling "Code braces" rule in `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Spaces : Within`